# Find a specific word inside a constructed string in C

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

Anyone can help me? i'm new in programming. How to make `str` and `str2` compareable? (with code if can). or any code that can find a spesific word inside CURLcode

```
int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "mabinogi.nexon.net");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection*/ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        const char *str = curl_easy_strerror(res);
        char *str2 = "nogi";
        char *ff = strstr(str,str2); /*how to make this compareable?*/
        if (ff) {
            printf("word found!");
        }
        printf(*str);

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) if you want to compare if two strings are the same or not.  But you need to change your `ff` to an `int` type, as `strcmp` returns `int`.

Comment: You should not search for strings in curl's error strings though. If you want to check for a specific curl error, use the CURLcode 'res' in this code snippet.